# Invoke-WebRequest failed - "Problems parsing json" with GitHub api

Tags: json, powershell, curl, github, graphql

I am attempting to communicate with the `Graphql` api through powershell. According to Github, one must first do the following `curl` call.

```
curl -H "Authorization: bearer token" -X POST -d " \
 { \
   \"query\": \"query { viewer { login }}\" \
 } \
" https://api.github.com/graphql
```

Using **GitHub Enterprise**, on powershell I do the following calls:

```
$url = "http://github.company.com/api/graphql" # note that it's http, not https

$body = "`"query`":`"query { viewer { login }}`""                                               #`

$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"

$headers.Add("content-type","application/json")

$headers.Add("Authorization","bearer myTokenNumber")

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method POST -Body $body -Headers $headers
```

I keep getting the same error message, that there are problems parsing JSON.

I assume the error is with the `body` tag, but I can't see how.

`echo $body` gives `"query":"query { viewer { login }}"`

What is the issue here?

Exact error message:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : {"message":"Problems parsing JSON","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}
At line:1 char:13
+ $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method POST -Body $body -Headers $heade ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Comment: Can you please share the exact error message?

Comment: Please check now

Comment: Have you tested your token and Query in GitHub's [GraphQL Explorer Interface](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/) ?

Comment: Works perfectly there

Comment: Is there a reason why you have to use the `http` version?

Comment: For a certain reason, `https` does not with github enterprise when I do it, but regardless, I tried this at home using `https` (normal git), and still the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164795/discussion-between-daniel-and-k-split-x).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `$body` value is malformed JSON, because it is missing the enclosing `{ ... }`.

Using a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) makes the construction of the JSON string easier:

```
$body = @'
{ "query": "query { viewer { login } }" }
'@
```

Similarly, you can simplify building the headers with a [hashtable literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables):

```
$headers = @{
  "content-type" = "application/json"
  "Authorization" = "bearer myTokenNumber"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the working program. Thanks to those who answered:

```
$url = "https://api.github.com/graphql" # regular github
# for enterprise it will be http(s)://[hostname]/api/graphql where hostname is 
# usually github.company.com ... try with both http and https

$body = @'
{ "query": "query { viewer { login } }" }
'@

$headers = @{
  "content-type" = "application/json"
  "Authorization" = "bearer tokenCode"
}

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method POST -Body $body -Headers $headers
Write-Host $response
```

Output: `{"data":{"viewer":{"login":"yourGithubUsername"}}}`